# ComboBox header not respecting ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

In a WPF project I have a `ComboBox` where the `DataTemplate` used for the  `ItemTemplate` changes the `Background` colour of a `Border` based on the `IsSelected` property of the `Person` object that the `ComboBoxItem`'s are bound to. So, in my example below, when `IsSelected=true` the `Background=LightGreen`.

All this is fine when the `ComboBox`'s dropdown is open. However, when the dropdown closes after selecting an item with `Background=LightGreen`, the `ComboBox`'s header doesn't show the `LightGreen` colour.

What do I need to do to show the `LightGreen` colour once the `ComboBox` has closed up on an `IsSelected=true` item?

Here is some example code to show what I mean.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="combo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:combo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}">
                         </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new Person[]
        {
            new Person() { Name = "Mickey" , Email= "m@disney.com" , IsSelected = false},
            new Person() { Name = "Donald" , Email= "d@disney.com", IsSelected = true },
            new Person() { Name = "Pluto" , Email= "p@disney.com", IsSelected = false }
        };
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RelativeSource` in your trigger looks for a `ComboBoxItem`, which you’ll only find in the `ItemsPresenter` inside the pop up the `ComboBox`.

[image: ItemsPres]

When the pop up is closed, what we see is a `ToggleButton` and a `ContentPresenter`.

[image: ContentPres]

In case the marking didn’t give it away:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Content.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                      AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about if you're talking about the way the ComboBox looks when closed, or if you are talking about the dropdown items background color not updating.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42562698/302677) already provides a solution for the first, but if you're wondering why the background color isn't updating on the selected item, it's because you are not binding `ComboBoxItem.IsSelected` to `Person.IsSelected` anywhere, so they are not synchronized.

Here's an example of how do add that binding :

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" >
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

That said, you may still have issues because you are not setting the default selected item. Typically when wanting to provide for single selection capabilitilikethis, I see this done more in the style of

```
ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
Person SelectedPerson { get; set; }
```

with XAML being

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
```

This way, you don't need to write any sync code to bind `ComboBoxItem.IsSelected` to your `Person.IsSelected`.

Comment: Hi @Rachel, thanks for your reply. It was the first option I was talking about, so apologies for any confusion. I should also have called the `IsSelected` property of my `Person` object something else, as I think this may have been the root of the confusion. Cheers.